# Sharp image processing without in-memory buffering using stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

I need to create a `/api/lqip` route to create base64 encoded image placeholders. Also, the question concerns normal image resizing.

I came across a technique for image processing without in-memory buffering using `PassThrough` (i.e. less server load) while exploring the remix image resizing example (https://github.com/remix-run/examples/blob/main/image-resize/app/routes/assets/resize/$.ts).

I'm not an expert in the backend, so I'm wondering should I use the sharp processing as regular or with stream.

[image: sharp processing using PassThrough]

[image: regular sharp processing]